# Stuck on 'Tap a surface to add the Local Anchor'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, azure-spatial-anchors

I'm trying to run through the instructions or the basic demo here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/quickstarts/get-started-unity-android  Everything seems to go fine however when running the app on my Galaxy S8+, the script seems to go no further than displaying the message 'Tap a surface to add the Local Anchor' with a Next Step button below.  No amount of tapping gets me further.

The camera is working.
I'm using Unity 2018.3.11f1
ARCore 1.50 as indicated in the instructions.

I've also tried exporting and building in Android studio and deploying and still nothing.  I did make sure I had ARCore Supported selected in the Player Settings --> XR Settings

Anyone else encounter this?

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages?

Comment: No.. No errors in the app.  Any recommendations on trying to debug?

Comment: Did you try and ensure you let ARCore recognise a surface properly? It works perfectly fine for me.